# ReactJS Material UI menu toggle issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make the Button and MenuItems toggle the open state of the Menu but once I click on it, it expands but doesn't close on second click.

```js
class Topbar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    anchorEl: null
  };

  handleClick = (event) => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };

  render() {
    const {anchorEl} = this.state;

    return (
      <>
          <Button onClick={handleClick}>Open Menu</Button>

          <Menu
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            keepMounted
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={handleClose}
          >
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a code sandbox with the issue it will help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are able to open the menu by clicking on the button since the `handleClick` function is undefined in the scope of the `render` function. Same goes for the `handleClose` function. These functions are members of your class and can only be accessed from other members of that class via `this`.

Change `onClick={handleClick}` to `onClick={this.handleClick}` and `onClick={handleClose}` to `onClick={this.handleClose}` and everything should work as expected.

Here is a working example:

[image: Edit focused-moon-n54dl]

Also note that `this.state.setAnchorEl` is not defined.

Comment: that was not an issue, I had changed and working but when I click again, it is not closing menu